# Spring 3's Quartz 2 implementation doesn't support requestsRecovery anymore

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, spring-3

According to the Quartz 2's [documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03)

> **RequestsRecovery** - if a job "requests recovery", and it is executing
>   during the time of a 'hard shutdown' of the scheduler (i.e. the
>   process it is running within crashes, or the machine is shut off),
>   then it is re-executed when the scheduler is started again. In this
>   case, the JobExecutionContext.isRecovering() method will return true.

Spring3 has support for both Quartz 1.x and Quartz 2.x. If we use Quartz 1.x then we need to use following configuration for creating `JobDetail` bean:

```
<bean id="ldapSynch" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.edfx.adb.scheduling.job.LDAPSynchronizer" />
    <property name="requestsRecovery" value="true" />       
</bean>
```

Internally `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean` extends `org.quartz.JobDetail` and in Quartz 1.x `org.quartz.JobDetail` has a setter `public void setRequestsRecovery(boolean shouldRecover)`.

But if we use Quartz 2.x implementation of Spring3 then the aforesaid configuration changes as:

```
<bean id="ldapSynch" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.edfx.adb.scheduling.job.LDAPSynchronizer" />
    <property name="requestsRecovery" value="true" />       
</bean>
```

And also in Quartz 2.x there is no such `org.quartz.JobDetail` class, instead it is an `interface` and eventually `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean` doesn't takes the parameter `<property name="requestsRecovery" value="true" />` anymore.

How could we pass this important `parameter` to the Quartz's scheduler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking into the source code of the class `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean` and source code of Quartz 2.0 I have found that there is a kind of `init method` in `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean` which is `public void afterPropertiesSet()`; within this method the instance of `org.quartz.JobDetail` is being created. Fortunately this instance of `org.quartz.JobDetail` can be accessible via a method `public JobDetail getObject()` of the class `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean`.

In Quartz 2.0 the class `org.quartz.impl.JobDeialImpl` implements the interface `org.quartz.JobDetail`; so the instance of `org.quartz.JobDetail` in `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean` is actually the instance of `org.quartz.impl.JobDeialImpl`.

So I created a class `com.edfx.adb.scheduling.ADBJobDetailFactoryBean` which extends `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean` and overrides the `afterPropertiesSet()` method as:

```
package com.edfx.adb.scheduling;

import org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean;

public class ADBJobDetailFactoryBean extends JobDetailFactoryBean {

    private boolean requestsRecovery;

    public ADBJobDetailFactoryBean() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
        JobDetailImpl jobDetail = (JobDetailImpl) getObject();
        jobDetail.setRequestsRecovery(isRequestsRecovery());
    }

    public boolean isRequestsRecovery() {
        return requestsRecovery;
    }

    public void setRequestsRecovery(boolean requestsRecovery) {
        this.requestsRecovery = requestsRecovery;
    }
}
```

And changed the spring bean configuration as:

```
<bean id="ldapSynch" class="com.edfx.adb.scheduling.ADBJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.edfx.adb.scheduling.job.LDAPSynchronizer" />
    <property name="requestsRecovery" value="true" />       
</bean>
```

And voila. I have tested this by stopping running server while the scheduler was executing the task and when I restarted the server the scheduler was started executing the unfinished job.

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

@tapas-bose while searching for some quartz info I come across your post. It looks like Spring 3.2 support setting the property *requestsRecovery*. I don't know which version of Spring 3.? you have mentioned in your answer with which you faced the problem.

I set requestsRecovery property directly through setter injection and it worked for me.

```
  <bean name="continousMonitoringProfileNotificationPushProcessing"     class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
  <property name="jobClass" value="com.mycompany.projectApp.jobs.ContinousMonitoringNotificationPushJobBean" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="executionSuccessful" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="durability" value="true" /> 
    <property name="requestsRecovery" value="true"/>
 </bean>
```

When I decompiled code for JobDetailFactoryBean it is overriding afterPropertiesSet method which creates JObDetailImpl instance and set requestsRecovery, (piece of decompiled code as below)

```
 public class JobDetailFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<JobDetail>, BeanNameAware, ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean
 {
 private String name;
 private String group;
 private Class jobClass;
 private JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
 private boolean durability = false;
 private boolean requestsRecovery = false;

...

.. 

..


 public void afterPropertiesSet()
{
  if (this.name == null) {
  this.name = this.beanName;
 }
  if (this.group == null) {
  this.group = "DEFAULT";
 }
if (this.applicationContextJobDataKey != null) {
 if (this.applicationContext == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("JobDetailBean needs to be set up in ApplicationContext to be able to handle an 'applicationContextJobDataKey'");
    }
 getJobDataMap().put(this.applicationContextJobDataKey, this.applicationContext);
 }
 Class<?> jobDetailClass;
 try
 {
      jobDetailClass = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("org.quartz.impl.JobDetailImpl");
  }
  catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
      jobDetailClass = JobDetail.class;
  }
  BeanWrapper bw = new BeanWrapperImpl(jobDetailClass);
  MutablePropertyValues pvs = new MutablePropertyValues();
  pvs.add("name", this.name);
  pvs.add("group", this.group);
  pvs.add("jobClass", this.jobClass);
  pvs.add("jobDataMap", this.jobDataMap);
  pvs.add("durability", Boolean.valueOf(this.durability));
  pvs.add("requestsRecovery", Boolean.valueOf(this.requestsRecovery));
```

So we don't need to manually extend the JobFactoryBean class and set the requestsRecovery property.